# What is ~":local(fadeIn)"?

Tags: css, less

I've encountered the following deep in my company's codebase and can't make heads or tails of it.

```
@keyframes ~ ":local(fadeIn)" {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.withFadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 500ms ease-in;
}
```

If it just said `@keyframes fadeIn {`, it would make total sense. But the tilde, the `:local()`, and the quotes are all utterly mysterious to me. Anyone recognize this?

Comment: Looks like [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). "… `:local` and `:local(…)` for local scope." The `~"…"` is similar to the [string escape](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) function in Less (it's not documented but it's used in the [replace](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace) function example.